# php urlencode in header location different from default urlencode in html anchor tag

Tags: php, html, urlencode

Am trying to redirect users from two different pages with a pair of similar variables.one page uses the HTML anchor tag while the other uses php header location.The one using anchor tag works fine but the one using header location does not work.Source codes are as shown below:

```
header("Location: Play.php?urlencode(vid_name='".$filehead."'&&uploader='".$uploader."')");
```

and

```
echo "<a href='Play.php?vid_name=".$songname." && uploader=".$uploader."'>";
```

am using the get method to use this variables. How can I sort this out so the recipient page can access the variables from header location?

Answer (score 0):

Functions dont run inside a double quoted string, but $variables are expanded

Try like this

```
header("Location: Play.php?" . urlencode("vid_name=$filehead&uploader=$uploader"));
```

and

```
echo "<a href='Play.php?vid_name=$songname&uploader=$uploader'>";
```

Or as @Victor suggested

```
$data = array(
    'vid_name' => $filehead,
    'uploader' => $uploader
);

echo header('Location: Play.php?' . http_build_query($data)  );
```

And

```
$data = array(
    'vid_name' => $songname,
    'uploader' => $uploader
);

echo "<a href='Play.php?" . http_build_query($data) . "'>";
```

Comment: Given the second example, I think you should encode each value separately. The function `http_build_query` may be exactly what he needs.

Comment: The first one didn't work for me because the variables were not sent as variables but as a string. The second one(suggestion from victor) works perfectly.Thanks